# How to connect to SQL Server through SSMS and don't understand naming convention?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wondering what types of naming conventions do I need to know when connecting to an instance of SQL Server via SSMS and within C# code, together with the meaning of naming conventions?

For example, why can you connect to a SQL Server database using the following as server name:  `MYTESTDB001,444`?

Is there another naming convention to use as we all know the likes of `localhost:1433`, `azure.mysetup.net:444`, can these be written and connected in a different way such as `MYTESTDB001:444`? Tried but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is the MSSQL instance installed on your local machine or outside somewhere?

Comment: Outside somewhere, for some reason I was given a MYTESTDB001,444 (obviously cannot disclose exact connection) but it says cannot find host? It follows exact format though, SERVERNAME,XXXX

Comment: `severname,portnumber` is a valid option. Looks like a network problem, "cannot find host"

Comment: I don't understand can I use hostname? or is this same thing? is there another format for servername,portnumber?

Comment: Check if dns resolves the given server name `MYTESTDB001`

Comment: What do you mean sorry?

Comment: Tried the nslookup command to find server name but now it says target machine refused? and it also timed out